# When minimizes StackPanel with Right HorizontalAlignment the end displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment, stackpanel, minimize

I have a window in `Wpf`, which presents a Grid that contains 3 StackPanels.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Text1"/>
        <Button Width="100" Margin="15,0" Content="Button1"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Text2"/>
        <Button Width="100" Margin="15,0" Content="Button2"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Text3"/>
        <Button Width="100" Margin="15,0" Content="Button3"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When I minimizes the window, the middle  StackPanel should disappear partially  (since the  ColumnDefinition where it is, defined as `Width = "*"`)

But, since that HorizontalAlignment is right, when I'm minimizes the window, the beginning of the StackPanel disappears and it shown the end (look at the pictures).

[image: Before minimizes]

[image: After minmizes]

I want that when I minimizes the end disappears (like the behavior in HorizontalAlignment = left), but I do not want to change the HorizontalAlignment

Anyone know a way to do it?

**EDIT-1:**

By the way, I came across a strange solution!
When I turn the middle StackPanel to DockPanel, it works!  I'll be happy if someone can explain why this is happening.

Besides, I was interested in a solution without changing the layout.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have taken the button size of 100 which is hard coded, So whenever the window is restored from maximize position the available size of the Grid's 2nd Column is also getting less than Buttons size so It is getting Clipped.

Set MinWidth of the Grid or Parent Window to get rid of this problem.